# Datastore's entity vs GCP Firestore's document

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, entity, document, datastore

How does GCP Datastore's entity differ from GCP Firestore's document? Are they pretty much the same (in their structure) with different name?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that they are both NoSQL **document database** built for scaling, flexibility, and performance so there's similarity in the concept:

| Concept | Datastore | Firestore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category of object | Kind | Collection group |
| One object | Entity | Document |
| Individual data for an object | Property | Field |
| Unique ID for an object. | Key | Document ID |

It's built around documents which are characterized by their schema-free organization of data that means:

- Records do not need to have a uniform structure, i.e. different records may have different columns.
- The types of the values of individual columns can be different for each record.
- Columns can have more than one value (arrays).
- Records can have a nested structure.

When in comes to hierarchical data structure, you can create subcollections on Firestore while on Datastore, you can achieve the similar thing by [creating a new entity, and assigning that created entity to another entity as its *parent*](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths). While the implementation is different, the structure is still the same.

Reference:
https://db-engines.com/en/article/Document+Stores